# JUnit application.properties always returning null

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I am trying to write unit tests for @Service annotated class. I have application.properties file set and a class to access the values.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String base_url;

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String firstName) {
        this.first_name = firstName;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String lastName) {
        this.last_name = lastName;
    }

    public String getBase_url() {
        return base_url;
    }

    public void setBase_url(String baseUrl) {
        this.base_url = baseUrl;
    }
}
```

and the test I wrote is like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { ApplicationProperties.class })
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class ServiceTests {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    @Before
    private void initializeConfig() {
        Mockito.when(applicationProperties.getFirst_name()).thenReturn("Karan");
    }

    @Test
    public void sample_Test() {
        MyService myService = new MyService();

        String fName = myService.getUserFirstName();

        assertEquals(fName, "Karan");
    }
}
```

and the method myService.getUserFirstName is like this

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    public String getUserFirstName() {
        return applicationProperties.getFirst_name();
    }
}
```

I tried following ways provided in this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669393/override-default-spring-boot-application-properties-settings-in-junit-test), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162777/how-do-i-mock-an-autowired-value-field-in-spring-with-mockito) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464408/spring-boot-accessing-application-properties-for-junit-test) stackoverflow questions. But it always have applicationProperties object null in the getUserFirstName method and throws null value exception.

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Have tried you making a `test/resources` directory and put a test copy of your `application.properties` in there?  This might work depending on your set up.

Comment: @Gavin, added the file as shown in updated image but still it is null.

Comment: follow this article https://reflectoring.io/unit-testing-spring-boot/